# Reduce gap between bars in chart js bar chart

Tags: reactjs, charts

I'm using chartjs for my react project. i created a bar chart and i want to reduce gap between the bars. I tried using "barPercentage" and "categoryPercentage" also. But it didn't work. I put my code below. Please mention what i'm doing wrong or suggest an option.

```
const data = {
    labels: ["Apple", "Orange", "Grapes", "Banana", "Kiwi"],
    datasets: [{
      data: [20, 50, 30, 35, 30, 20],
      barPercentage: 1.0,
      categoryPercentage: 1.0,
      backgroundColor: ['#B2DED4', '#81CAB8', '#81CAB8', '#4FB59D', '#2BA489'],
      borderColor: '#707070',
      borderWidth: 1,
      barThickness: 16,
      borderRadius: 10,
    }],
  }

  const options = {
    scales: {
      y: {
        title: {
          display: true,
        },
        grid: {
          display: true,
        },
      },
      x: {
        title: {
          display: true,
        },
        grid: {
          display: false,
        }
      }
    },
    plugins: {
      legend: {
        display: false,
      },
      datalabels: {
        display: false
      }
    },
  }

<Bar data={data} options={options} />
```

Answer (score 0):

The only problem is because you specify the `barThickness` in `dataset` options which have will prevent `barPercentage` from taking effect. Just remove it and configure the `barPercentage` to any amount that you prefer, you don't need `categoryPercentage` in this case.

```js
const data = {
    labels: ["Apple", "Orange", "Grapes", "Banana", "Kiwi"],
    datasets: [{
      data: [20, 50, 30, 35, 30, 20],
      barPercentage: 1.0,
      // categoryPercentage: 1.0,
      backgroundColor: ['#B2DED4', '#81CAB8', '#81CAB8', '#4FB59D', '#2BA489'],
      borderColor: '#707070',
      borderWidth: 1,
      // barThickness: 16,
      borderRadius: 10,
    }],
  }
```

Hope this could help!

Comment: hi @Anh Tran thanks for the reply. After remove barThicknes, bar width has increased. barPercentage value also sets the bar width. It still doesn't work for me. I want to reduce bar width and also the gaps between them.  by decreasing barPercentage i reduced the width. But the gap still remains